# Finding the explicit expression of a conformal map

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I want to find a conformal map $f$ between $D = \{z\in\Bbb C : |Arg(z)|<\frac \pi4\}\setminus[1,+\infty)$ and $D(0,R)$, for $R$ a real positive number that I have to compute as well. It also has to verify that, for $z_0 = \frac 12$, $f(z_0) = 0$ and $f'(z_0) = 1$.

So far I have tried the following:

- First, I use the map $z\mapsto \frac 1z$, so $D$ is conformally equivalent to $D_1 = \{z\in\Bbb C : |Arg(z)|<\frac \pi4\}\setminus[0,1]$.
- Then, I use the map $z\mapsto z^4$ to 'close' the sector and have $D_2 = \Bbb C\setminus (-\infty,1]$.
- Now, I take the map $z\mapsto z-1$ to move $D_2$ into $D_3 = \Bbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]$.
- I 'reopen' $D_3$ with $z\mapsto \sqrt z$ and get $D_4 = \{z : Re(z) >0\}$.
- Finally, I use the Möbius transformation $T(z) = \frac{1+z}{1-z}$, and reach to the unit disc $\Bbb D$.

Of course, this does not verify that $f(z_0) = 0$, so I tried changing the last step in order for it to be verified, so an alternate Möbius transformation would be $T(z) = \frac{-\sqrt{15}+z}{1-z}$, but I'm sure that this does not give me the conformal map that I'm looking for either.

Could anyone please help me out? Am I complicating this too much, or can it be changed so the computation gets easier?

Comment: do you know what the automorphisms of the unit disc look like? if yes then its easy to see that once you have one conformal map to the disc, you can compose by an appropriate automorphism to ensure that a given point is mapped to the origin, and that the derivative is positive.

Comment: I'm going through my notes and the only thing regarding a morphism that sends the disc to itself is the map $T(z) = \lambda \frac{a-z}{1-\overline{a}z}$, with $|\lambda|=1$ and $|a|<1$. Is that what you are refering to?

Comment: yes let me call that $S_{a,\lambda}$ rather than $T$ as you have. So, using your current $f$ (as the composition of 5 maps), let $a=f(z_0)$, and $\lambda= e^{- i\text{arg}(f'(z_0))}$ so that by considering $S_{a,\lambda}\circ f$, we map $z_0$ to the origin and then rotate appropriately to ensure $(S_{a,\lambda}\circ f)'(0)$ is positive. If you now want to ensure the derivative is exactly equal to $1$, then you're going to have to map the unit disc to a disc of another radius (currently I'm not sure if there's a shortcut to all of this... I myself only recently learnt this stuff)

Comment: So by using that expression, we would have that, let's call it $g$ since $f$ is being used for the composition of 5 maps, $g(z_0) = 0$ and $g'(z_0)>0$. I'd imagine that a few more tweaks would make me have $g'(z_0) = 1$. And also that $R = 1$, since we are still in the unit disc, right?

Comment: $g$ maps your domain $D$ conformally onto the unit disc such that $g(z_0)=0$ and $g'(z_0)>0$. Now, let $R=\frac{1}{g'(z_0)}$ (which we know is positive), and consider the mapping $h(z)=\frac{g(z)}{R}$. This is conformal, $h(z_0)=0$ and $h'(z_0)=1$.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: lol I may have put too many reciprocals. We want $h(z)=Rg(z)$.